# Why am I getting insufficient parameters supplied to the command error?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have trying to read a database and display it into a datagridview, but I keep getting the error, using [Windows Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) and SQLite:

```
private void nameSearch()
{
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connAccount.CreateCommand())
    {
        connAccount.Open();
        try
        {
            connAccount = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection.source);

            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT accid, account.custid, customer.title,
                                customer.firstname || ' ' || customer.lastname AS Name,
                                product.isaname AS ProductName, balance,
                                accrued, active
                                FROM account INNER JOIN customer ON customer.custid = account.custid
                                INNER JOIN product ON product.prodid = account.prodid
                                WHERE Name = @setName";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setName", txt_name.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            da_Accounts = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, connAccount);
            dt_Accounts = new DataTable();
            da_Accounts.Fill(dt_Accounts);
            dgv_Account.DataSource = dt_Accounts;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

That's the code I'm using, but what is the issue?

I have tried removing the concatenation, and I’ve tried changing the parameters method too:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@setName", DbType.String).Value = txt_name.Text;
```

I tried with and without the executenonquery() each time.

Comment: It's gotta have something to do with that `|| ' ' ||`.  I've never seen that in SQL before, and I doubt very much that it is valid SQL, but I've been proven wrong before.

Comment: iim doing a college course and that is the way they showed us to get the values from 2 or more colums and put them into 1 with a space between them, i have tried it with the columns added in as they are in the table but same error si dont think it is || ' ' || thats the issue

Comment: OK, well apparently SQLite supports Oracle's convention of two vertical bars being a concatenation operator.  For what it's worth, the way your college course is doing database access is *very old.*  The use of `AddWithValue` is considered a bad practice; see [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: it doesnt say i just get a message box pop up

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery has nothing to do with a SELECT query. Could you remove that line and verify?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you cannot use Name in the WHERE statement. Try to repeat the concatenation in the WHERE statement

Comment: so just tried reapeating the concatenation in the where statement and still get the same error sadly, the cmd.executenonquery() was only there because i threw it in after i got the error the first time just incase but deleted after, ive tried removing the concatenation and still doesnt solve it

Comment: Verify the names of your fields in the SELECT. Mispelling one field here could trigger the parser to consider the mispelled field as a parameter placeholder (At least this happens with some other file level databases) Other debugging option could be removing fields or joins until the error disappear and then focus on the field or join failing

Comment: what is the value of txt_name? I don't see that being set anywhere

Comment: its a textbox and this code is called inside a textchange event

Comment: @Steve so i just tried it on another part of my application where i have no joins simple 1 table and get the same error

Comment: @adrian38 I'm not an expert in C# but try to move `connAccount = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection.source);` before `using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connAccount.CreateCommand())`.

Comment: no joy still get the same error

Comment: It seems odd that you create `cmd` with  `SQLiteCommand cmd = connAccount.CreateCommand()` and then you create a new connection with `connAccount = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection.source);`.

Comment: that part ive deleted now as it wasnt needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got it working. The issue was with the line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@setName", txt_name.Text);
```

I had to delete this line and add the parameters to the actual adapter. And now it's working.

```
try
{
    conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection.source);

    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM customer WHERE lastname = @Name";

    da_Customer = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn);
    da_Customer.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", txt_name.Text);
    dt_Customer = new DataTable();
    da_Customer.Fill(dt_Customer);
    dgv_customer.DataSource = dt_Customer;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```